# Robust way to handle options in awk

Tags: awk

I am looking for a robust way to handle user-defined options in awk.  It does not help to use obscure values, or care whether a variable is set or not.

Flags are set to specific values.  If I do not see those values set, I would set them to a default, which may be null.

For instance, `-v db=7` sets debug level.  If `db` has no value (including being non-existent), no debug.  If it has a value that is non-empty, and not numeric or out of range, I complain and abort the run.

How can I implement such thing, and would it be robust enough?

Till now I have been using

```
if (opt) { do_this}
if (!opt) {do_that}
```

Comment: *`How can I implement such thing`* ... what have you tried so far? *`would it be robust enough`* ... define *your* idea of `robust` ... not provided, non-integer, integer but-out-of-range, integer and in range ... what else is there?

Comment: Have also seen code containing `;` at the end of the line.  Is that really necessary?

Comment: the `;` is required (as a command separator) when placing multiple commands on the same line (eg, 'one-liners') otherwise the `;` is not *required*; the `;` could be leftover from reformatting (eg, one-liner to multi-lines); net result: the `;` on the end of the line does no harm

Comment: so, what's wrong wtih your current approach to testing `opt`? I'm assuming you've actually got more details than this example, eg, testing for datatype, validating 'legal' datatype range/values ... ??

Comment: I could also set a default with `if (! db) { db = 1 }` to set a default.  Just inquiring what would be most readable for others working upon my code.

Comment: what others consider 'readable' is open to discussion, debate and ultimately opinion/preference; using meaningful names is usually beneficial though easy to go overboard (eg, `debug_level_int`);  fwiw, this question is likely to be closed due to not meeting SO requirements (eg, does not attempt to address a specific technical/coding issues) but instead is requesting opinions

Comment: Nitpic: there is no such thing in Awk as `db` being nonexistent. If you access the value of `db` in the Awk code, then Awk knows about that variable. The GNU Awk implementation will put it into a global symbol table, where it is known that it exists with an undefined value, before any of the code executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> non-existent

This is easy to check in GNU `AWK`, just look if [`typeof(db)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Type-Functions.html) is `"untyped"`.

> not numeric

I suggest following heuristics: if `typeof(db)` is not `"strnum"` then it is not numeric.

Answer (score 1):

In portable Awk code, you can detect an undefined value because it compares to zero and the empty string at the same time:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print (a == "" && a == 0) }'
1
$ awk -v a= 'BEGIN { print (a == "" && a == 0) }'
0
$ awk -v a=0 'BEGIN { print (a == "" && a == 0) }'
0
```

We know in the special case when `a` is simultaneously equal to zero and empty string that it has the undefined value, and so was not set on the command line via `-v`; in that case we can substitute our desired default value.

Comment: I used to think that `a` would not be simultaneously a string and numeric.  Which got me to some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 1 : hopefully this should be able to consistently detect between the 3 states across all these `awk` invocation combinations :

```
for ___ in 'gawk -p- -e ' 'gawk -Pe' 'gawk -ce' 'gawk -nbe' \
           'gawk     -e'  'mawk1'    'mawk2'    'nawk'     ; do

   printf ' %-10s :: %s\n' "$___" "$( $( printf '%s' "$___" ) '

   function __(_) { 
       return     (_==!+_)^(_==(_)_) ? "scalar" \
              : ((_<_)==_)^(_~ (_)_) ? "undefined / no-input" \
                                     : "blank / null-string-input"    
   } BEGIN { 
         OFS = "\f\r\t"
         print "", __(), __(db),        __(db=""), __(db =    "0"),
                     __(db = 0),      __(db = 17), __(db = "|.{}"),
                  __(db = OFMT), __("0.00000009"), __(" -9_A") }'   )"
done
```

> 

```
 gawk -p- -e  :: 
    undefined / no-input
    undefined / no-input
    blank / null-string-input
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    # gawk profile, created Thu Mar  2 20:29:17 2023

    # BEGIN rule(s)

    BEGIN {
     1      OFS = "\f\r\t"
     1      print "", __(), __(db), __(db = ""), __(db = "0"), __(db = 0), __(db = 17), __(db = "|.{}"), __(db = OFMT), __("0.00000009"), __(" -9_A")
    }

    # Functions, listed alphabetically

    10  function __(_)
    {
    10      return  (_ == !+_) ^ (_ == (_)_) ? "scalar" \
                : ((_<_) == _) ^ (_ ~  (_)_) ? "undefined / no-input" \
                                             : "blank / null-string-input"
    }

 gawk -Pe   :: 
    undefined / no-input
    undefined / no-input
    blank / null-string-input
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
 gawk -ce   :: 
    undefined / no-input
    undefined / no-input
    blank / null-string-input
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
 gawk -nbe  :: 
    undefined / no-input
    undefined / no-input
    blank / null-string-input
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
 gawk -e    :: 
    undefined / no-input
    undefined / no-input
    blank / null-string-input
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
 mawk1      :: 
    undefined / no-input
    undefined / no-input
    blank / null-string-input
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
 mawk2      :: 
    undefined / no-input
    undefined / no-input
    blank / null-string-input
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
 nawk       :: 
    undefined / no-input
    undefined / no-input
    blank / null-string-input
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
    scalar
```

==============

here's a multi-`awk` compatible testing function that should handle reasonable input, including numeric strings, but would fail if the input is something strange like `" -9_A"`. :

```
for ___ in 'gawk -p- -e ' 'gawk -Pe' 'gawk -ce' 'gawk -nbe' \
           'gawk     -e'  'mawk1'    'mawk2'    'nawk'     ; do

     printf ' %-10s :: %s\n' "$___" "$( $( printf '%s' "$___" ) '
  
        function __(_) { 
            return !+_ && _ && _!=+_ \
                        ?     "debug" \
                        : "non-debug" 
        } 
        BEGIN { print __(db),      __(db = "0" ), __(db = 0),
                      __(db = 17), __(db = OFMT), __("0.00000009") }' )"
 done
```

> 

```
 gawk -p- -e  :: non-debug non-debug non-debug non-debug debug non-debug
    # gawk profile, created Thu Mar  2 20:03:44 2023

    # BEGIN rule(s)

    BEGIN {
     1      print __(db),       __(db = "0"),       __(db = 0), 
                  __(db = 17), __(db = OFMT), __("0.00000009")
    }

    # Functions, listed alphabetically

     6  function __(_)
    {
     6      return (!+_ && _ && _!=+_) ? "debug" : "non-debug"
    }
 gawk -Pe   :: non-debug non-debug non-debug non-debug debug non-debug
 gawk -ce   :: non-debug non-debug non-debug non-debug debug non-debug
 gawk -nbe  :: non-debug non-debug non-debug non-debug debug non-debug
 gawk -e    :: non-debug non-debug non-debug non-debug debug non-debug
 mawk1      :: non-debug non-debug non-debug non-debug debug non-debug
 mawk2      :: non-debug non-debug non-debug non-debug debug non-debug
 nawk       :: non-debug non-debug non-debug non-debug debug non-debug
```

The messiest part was how to remove eligibility for all `numeric` and `string` based zeros.